# Bauch Family records Berlin-Charlottenburg

Tags: germany, death-records, berlin

How can I find out about my grandfather's siblings?

Would a German death certificate for my great grandfather have his immediate family listed?

I know (Josef) Alois Bauch was born in Allenstein, Wadang in 1876 BUT I only estimate that my great grandfather died in 1950/60 so am having trouble pinning down a death certificate.

Berlin telephone directories and a photo have the family in Berlin up until 1922.

Answer (score 6):

Ancestry.com has [a marriage record](http://interactive.ancestry.de/2957/41539_prep553_000069-00268?pid=22168509) ($) for Alois Bauch (marriage to Selma Günther on 28 March 1905). A side note lists only one son, born 1907 (number 160/1907 Wilmersdorf), who married in 1940 in Wilhelmshaven (number  455?/1940). If city directories don’t list the family later than 1922, it is possible that Alois Bauch either died (and his wife is listed then) or the family moved.

I could not find a death certificate for Alois Bauch. What is listed there, depends on [when the certificate was issued](http://landesarchiv-berlin.de/personenstandsunterlagen-2#inhalt). It is unlikely that his (whole) family would be listed there. Sometimes the family member who reported the death is named.

Digitized name indices [are available from Landesarchiv Berlin](http://landesarchiv-berlin.de/personenstandsunterlagen-2#namensverzeichnisse), you can search them by register office and type of record.

Furthermore you can request information from the *[Einwohnermeldekartei](http://landesarchiv-berlin.de/einwohnermeldekartei)* on family members from the Landesarchiv, but wartime losses are likely.

You could try to get the birth certificate for his wife, Selma Günther, who was born in [Staßfurt](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/STAURTJO51TU) 4 June 1877 and see if you can trace her death certificate and thus her whereabouts in later years.

**Update 3 March 2017**

The birth certificate is not available from Ancestry, as their collection on Berlin birth records spans only the period form 1874 to 1899. As the son was born in 1907 his birth records should be available from the Landesarchiv (state archiv) **after** 2017 (after 110 years). Until then [Bezirksamt Charlottenburg-Wilmersdorf](https://www.berlin.de/ba-charlottenburg-wilmersdorf/verwaltung/aemter/amt-fuer-buergerdienste/standesamt/geburtenregister/artikel.178126.php) should have the birth records. You can request a **copy** („nicht-beglaubigte Kopie mit allen Randvermerken“) from them for a fee. Don’t ask for a birth certificate, as they might provide you a modern printout with only limited data. Access restrictions might apply, it certainly helps to outline your relationship and to tell them when your uncle died (if known). If they don’t grant you a copy you have to wait until it is handed over to the archives and other rules apply.

Comment: Hi Lejonet"A side note lists only one son, born 1907 (no 160/1907 Wilmersdorf), who married in 1940 in Wilhelmshaven (no 455?/1940)."

Comment: hi Leojonet, Re "A side note lists only one son, born 1907 (no 160/1907 Wilmersdorf), who married in 1940 in Wilhelmshaven (no 455?/1940)" - I searched Ancestry.com but couldn't for the life of me find those numbers in brackets let alone that birth you refer to.  BUT..... I am pretty excited, because I think this is my Onkel Eter/Ather because he was in the navy and was living at Wilhelmshaven.

Comment: ....... could you post more concise details.  Many thanks!

Comment: @MHS I updated my answer. Please consider accepting my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers regarding date span and the particular type of "copy" of the birth certificate for my uncle.  In the meantime, I don't actually know the actual spelling of my uncle's christian name

Comment: ......... Could you please provide me with the name of the son born in 1907 aka my uncle.  Also, was there a name noted for my uncle's wife whom he married in 1940?

Comment: @MHS Sorry, there is no information on the uncle’s name. The name indices linked above are still not accessible for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you lejonet & polygeo.  I now have some record offices to pursue and the background information has been useful.

Comment: With regard to my Bauch family and german names.

Comment: ...... could someone let me know if there is a German christian name or nickname which sounds like Ether / Ete / Ӓther.  I think this is the name of the uncle who lived in Wilhemshaven in about 1940s.

Comment: @MHS The only name I am aware of is "Eitel", but it is very rare and it has especially been in use together with other names for members of nobility

Comment: Thanks so much for all this information and assistance.  I have a better understanding of records in Germany and can get somewhere now that I found this great site.

Comment: As luck would have it I have found my second cousin in the Wilhelmshaven phone book and now have a bit more information.  It seems one of my gt uncle's brothers could not pronounce the name Eric and always went by a mispronounced derivation Ehte!  Thanks everyone.

Comment: @MHS we have two ways to thank here which you may not be used to.  The first is to upvote any questions and answers that you find useful.  The other is to click the green checkmark next to one answer on your own questions.  This is called accepting an answer and should normally be done to reward the person whose answer helped you the most.